# wysiwyg inline markup editor?

Tags: html, custom-controls, rich-text-editor

What I mean by this is something a bit like the stackoverflow markup editor (type markup with realtime rendering) but in a single element, as opposed to having a second window.

This would let the user type "[[blahblah]]" and the text would get swapped out for a link to /blahblah. If the user hits backspace, the link should change back to "[[blahblah]". This is a fairly basic use case, I have a few more interesting uses for such a library.

I can imagine writing some editor which redirects keystrokes to a textarea, then re-renders to an overlay after each keystroke, and re-positions the caret on the overlay, but it sounds pretty fiddly! Is there some library that does this, where you define a simple grammar and it does the rest?

edit:

Comment: @st3fan It's completely inappropriate to edit a question in order to try to get more attention for your (now deleted) self-promotional answer to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for something like this:

http://podio.github.io/jquery-mentions-input/

[image]